# If $\Delta u_n = 0$ in $B_1$, show that $u_n \to u$ locally uniformly and $\Delta u = 0$ in $B_1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let $u_n$ be a sequence of functions defined on $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $|u_n|\leq C$, for some constant $C\geq 1$. If $\Delta u_n = 0$ in $B_1$ then (up to a subsequence) $u_n \to u$ locally and uniformly in $B_1$ and moreover $\Delta u = 0$ in $B_1$

If I show that the Mean Value Theorem holds then that would imply that $u$ is harmonic. Then, because $\Delta u_n = 0$ we have that:
$$u_n (x) = \int_{B_r (x)} u_n dx \hspace{1cm} \text{( - average integral)}$$
Then, we can just pass the limit so that 
$$u(x) = \int_{B_r(x)} udx \hspace{1cm} \text{( - average integral)}$$
so that the mean value theorem holds, and thus $\Delta u = 0$

However, I am not sure how to show that $u_n \to u$ locally and uniformly though in the first place.

Comment: Hint: Use Harnack's Inequality to obtain equicontinuity on compact subsets. Then use Arzela-Ascoli.